# Basic of quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, hilbert-space, superposition

It's a small problem that is bothering me for a long time. Suppose I have a system in a state $ \psi_i$. It is a linear superposition of several states, let's say $$\psi_i = a\psi_1 + b\psi_2$$ with $|a|^2 ≤1$, $|b|^2 ≤1$ and $|a|^2 + |b|^2 =1$ . Now this system has a probability of interacting with another system which has a definite state and the probability of interaction is $$e,$$ and the former system ( after interaction ) reaches the final state  $$\psi_f = c\psi_1 + d\psi_2$$ with $|c|^2 ≤1$, $|d|^2 ≤1$ and $|c|^2 + |d|^2 =1$. 
So my question is :

Is there any meaning attached to the statement $$\langle\psi_f|e|\psi_i\rangle   ?$$

If so, then what is the meaning?

Comment: If you consider "e" as begin a probability, then this quantity is just a real number so in the last statement e can get in front...

Comment: Okay, then what happens? What's the meaning of the rest? And if it has a meaning, how do I calculate it out explicitly?

Comment: Are $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ orthogonal?

Comment: Yeah, they are orthogonal base pairs.

Comment: What does "probability of interaction" mean? That's not standard terminology in quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $e$ is a real number (i.e. a probability), the quantity $\langle\psi_f|e|\psi_i\rangle$ is actually just $e\langle\psi_f|\psi_i\rangle$. The quantity $\langle\psi_f|\psi_i\rangle$ is typically called the "overlap" of the state $|\psi_f\rangle$ with the state $|\psi_i\rangle$. It's an analogue of the dot product (it's actually an inner product, which behaves similarly). The inner product operation is conjugate-linear in the first argument and linear in the second argument by definition,* and so we can separate components as follows:

\begin{align*}
\langle\psi_f|\psi_i\rangle &= \langle c\psi_1+d\psi_2|a\psi_1+b\psi_2\rangle\\
&=\langle c\psi_1|a\psi_1+b\psi_2\rangle+\langle d\psi_2|a\psi_1+b\psi_2\rangle\\
&=\langle c\psi_1|a\psi_1\rangle+\langle c\psi_1|b\psi_2\rangle+\langle d\psi_2|a\psi_1\rangle+\langle d\psi_2|b\psi_2\rangle\\
&=c^*a\langle\psi_1|\psi_1\rangle+c^*b\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle+d^*a\langle\psi_2|\psi_1\rangle+d^*b\langle\psi_2|\psi_2\rangle
\end{align*}

Assuming $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$ are an orthonormal basis, then $\langle \psi_1|\psi_1\rangle=\langle\psi_2|\psi_2\rangle=1$ and $\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle=\langle\psi_2|\psi_1\rangle=0$, meaning that $\langle\psi_f|\psi_i\rangle=c^*a+d^*b$.

*This is not the usual definition adopted by mathematicians, but is common in physics. In mathematics, the first argument is linear and the second argument is conjugate-linear.

Comment: Well, thank you for this beautiful answer. But can you clear one doubt? Why did we take c'*a and not a'*c ? Is it because of the arrangement? And why do we even take the conjugate?

Comment: $c$ and $a$ are complex numbers, which commute, so $c^*a=ac^*$.  We take the conjugate because that is how the inner product is defined; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space.